# Preencher 3 selects sem repetições

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Boa noite,

Em uma view preciso preencher 3 select sem repetições.

No formulário de inscrição em um processo seletivo preciso que o estudante escolha no primeiro select a primeira opção de curso, no segundo select escolha a segunda opção de curso e diferente da primeira opção, no terceiro select escolha a terceira opção de curso e diferente da primeira e segunda opções.

Já implementei alguns códigos e o máximo que consegui foi isso:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

segundaOpcao2();

$("#primeira_opcao").change(function () {

    $("#segunda_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
    $("#terceira_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

    if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        segundaOpcao($(this).val());
    } else {
        $("#segunda_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        $("#terceira_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
    }
});


function segundaOpcao2() {

    if ($("#primeira_opcao").val() > 0) {
        segundaOpcao($(this).val());
    } else {
        $("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
    }
}

$("#segunda_opcao").change(function () {

    //$("#terceira_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

    if (($("#segunda_opcao").val() != $("#primeira_opcao").val()) && $("#primeira_opcao").val() > 0 && $("#segunda_opcao").val() > 0) {
        terceiraOpcao($("#primeira_opcao").val(), $("#segunda_opcao").val());
    } else {
        $("#segunda_opcao").empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        $("#terceira_opcao").attr("disabled", true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

    }
});

function terceiraOpcao2() {
    if ($("#segunda_opcao").val() > 0) {
        segundaOpcao($(this).val());
    } else {
        primeiraOpcao2();
    }

}

/*
    // Primeira opção de curso
    function primeiraOpcao() {

        $("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

        var dataID = $("#primeira_opcao").attr('id-data-opcao1');
        $("#primeira_opcao").html("Carregando...");
        $.post("/psei2018/primeira_opcao",
            function (data) {
                cursos = eval(data);
                $("#primeira_opcao").empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
                for (i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {

                    $("#primeira_opcao").append("<option value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");

                }
            });
        $("#primeira_opcao").removeAttr('disabled',true);

    }
    */

// Segunda opção de curso
function segundaOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao) {

    //$("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
    //$("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

    var idPrimeiraOpcao = idPrimeiraOpcao;

    var dataID = $("#segunda_opcao").attr('id-data-opcao2');

    $("#segunda_opcao").html("Carregando...");

    $.post("/psei2018/segunda_opcao", {idPrimeiraOpcao: idPrimeiraOpcao},

        function (data) {
            cursos = eval(data);
            $("#segunda_opcao").removeAttr('disabled');

            $("#segunda_opcao").append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

            for (i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {
                if (idPrimeiraOpcao != cursos[i].id) {
                    $("#segunda_opcao").append("<option value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });


}

// Terceira Opção d curso
function terceiraOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao, idSegundaOpcao) {

    var idPrimeiraOpcao = idPrimeiraOpcao;
    var idSegundaOpcao = idSegundaOpcao;
    var dataID = $("#terceira_opcao").attr('id-data-opcao3');

    $("#terceira_opcao").html("Carregando...");
    $.post("/psei2018/terceira_opcao", {idPrimeiraOpcao: idPrimeiraOpcao, idSegundaOpcao: idSegundaOpcao},
        function (data) {
            cursos = eval(data);
            $("#terceira_opcao").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#terceira_opcao").html("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
            for (i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {
                if (idPrimeiraOpcao != cursos[i].id && idSegundaOpcao != cursos[i].id) {
                    $("#terceira_opcao").append("<option value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    //$("#terceira_opcao").removeAttr("disabled",true);

}

});
```

O preenchimento dos select está funcionando parcialmente. O principal problema ocorre quando algum outro campo do formulário der erro e retornar para a view o estudante resolver alterar novamente os selects. Aí os selects 2 e 3 não funcionam mais corretamente.

Comment: Veja se é isto: a primeira opção aparece as opções normal e as outras desabilitadas, quando seleciona uma, carrega via ajax a segunda opção, selecionando a segunda opção carrega tb via ajax a terceira. Caso ele mude a segunda, deve carregar novamente a terceira. Caso ele mude a primeira, a segunda deve ser novamente carregada e a terceira desabilitada.

Answer (score 1):

com jQuery, você pode fazer isso abrindo um loop pelos elementos e opções, e comparando os valores, segue comentado no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  //Captando o ID do select modificado
  var $thisSelect = $this.closest('select').attr('id');
  //Recebendo o valor dessa mudanca
  var $thisValue = $this.val();
  //Aqui voce abre um loop pelos selects
  $("select").each(function( selIndex ) {
    //Identificando o select do loop
    var $eachSelectEL = $(this); 
    //Pegando o ID do select do loop
    var $eachSelect = $(this).attr('id');
    //Agora compara se o select do loop nao e o mesmo do evento
    if($eachSelect !== $thisSelect){
      //Caso nao seja, abra um loop pelas options
      $eachSelectEL.find("option").each(function( optIndex ) {
        //Receba o valor da option
        var $eachOption = $(this).val();
        //Caso o valor da option seja o mesmo do selecionado no evento 
        if($eachOption === $thisValue){
          //Adiciona a propriedade disable
          $(this).prop('disabled',true)
        }
      })  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='select-grp'>
<select id='select1'>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id='select2'>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id='select3'>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Funciona com quantos selects e options quiser.

**OBS 2:** Dentro dos loops, voce pode fazer um consulta ajax e preencher caso deva mudar os valores das options.

Answer (score 1):

Eu entendi que tinha uma hierarquia nos selects(s1>s2>s3) sendo assim o select 2 não pode impedir que o 1 selecione um valor qualquer e sugiro a sequinte solução

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
     if($(this).attr('id') == "select1") {
        $('#select2').attr('disabled', false);
        if($('#select2').val() == $(this).val()){
          $('#select2').val('-');
          $('#select3').attr('disabled', true);
        }
        $('#select2 option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
          .attr('disabled',true);
        if($('#select3').val() == $(this).val())
          $('#select3').val('-');
        $('#select3 option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
          .attr('disabled',true);
     }
     if($(this).attr('id') == "select2" ) {
        $('#select3').attr('disabled', false);
        if($('#select3').val() == $(this).val())
          $('#select3').val('-');
        $('#select3 option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]')
          .attr('disabled',true);
     }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='select-grp'>
<select id='select1'>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id='select2' disabled>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id='select3' disabled>
  <option disabled selected>-</option>
  <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
  <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
  <option value="opt3">Opt3</option>
  <option value="opt4">Opt4</option>
  <option value="opt5">Opt5</option>
  <option value="opt6">Opt6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnthraxisBR usei seu html

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', true);
    $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true);

    $("#primeira_opcao").on("change", function () {

        var idPrimeiraOpcao = $(this).val();
        if (idPrimeiraOpcao > 0) {
            $("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', false);

            segundaOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao);
        } else {
            $("#segunda_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
            $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        }
    });

    $("#primeira_opcao").trigger("change");

    function segundaOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao) {

        console.log('segunda opcao');

        var idPrimeiraOpcao = idPrimeiraOpcao;

        var dataID = $("#segunda_opcao").attr('id-data-opcao2');

        $("#segunda_opcao").html("Carregando...");

        $.post("/psei2018/segunda_opcao", {idPrimeiraOpcao: idPrimeiraOpcao},
            function (data) {
                cursos = eval(data);
                $("#segunda_opcao").removeAttr('disabled');

                $("#segunda_opcao").append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");

                for (i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {

                    if (dataID == cursos[i].id) {
                        $("#segunda_opcao").append("<option selected value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                        $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', false);
                        terceiraOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao, dataID);
                    } else {
                        $("#segunda_opcao").append("<option value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                    }

                }
            });
    }

    $("#segunda_opcao").on("change", function () {

        var idSegundaOpcao = $(this).val();
        var idPrimeiraOpcao = $('#primeira_opcao').val();
        if (idSegundaOpcao > 0) {
            $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', false);
            terceiraOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao, idSegundaOpcao);
        } else {
            $("#terceira_opcao").attr('disabled', true).empty().append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        }
    });

    $("#segunda_opcao").trigger("change");

    function terceiraOpcao(idPrimeiraOpcao, idSegundaOpcao) {

        var idPrimeiraOpcao = idPrimeiraOpcao;
        var idSegundaOpcao = idSegundaOpcao;
        var dataID = $("#terceira_opcao").attr('id-data-opcao3');

        $("#terceira_opcao").html("Carregando...");
        $.post("/psei2018/terceira_opcao", {idPrimeiraOpcao: idPrimeiraOpcao, idSegundaOpcao: idSegundaOpcao},
            function (data) {
                cursos = eval(data);
                $("#terceira_opcao").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#terceira_opcao").html("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
                for (i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {

                    if (dataID == cursos[i].id) {
                        $("#terceira_opcao").append("<option selected value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                    } else {
                        $("#terceira_opcao").append("<option value='" + cursos[i].id + "'>" + cursos[i].campus + " - " + cursos[i].sigla + " - " + cursos[i].nome + "</option>");
                    }

                }
            });


    }
});
```

Um amigo do trabalho resolveu o problema com o código acima.

Agora as opções de curso não são repetidas, nem mesmo quando há retorno de erro do servidor pelo preenchimento incorreto de algum outro campo do formulário.